# How to Pass a value from Process studiio to Object Studio using Input Output Parameters in BluePrism?

Tags: input, parameters, output, blueprism, rpa

In Process Studio at page1 I had a Data item and some value in it and I want to call this value from Object Studio Using Input Output Parameters.
I tried to set Input Parameters in object studio by double clicking on Start Stage. But where to declare Output Parameters in process studio and at what stage exactly?

Comment: Are you attempting to have the **object** output data *back* to the **process**?

Answer (score 2):

Input Parameters are defined in the Start element. Output Parameters are defined in the End element.

Answer (score 1):

Gere is a solution:

1. Go to object studio and add input parameter at start stage of an object.
2. Go to process studio - Add action stage and select the object from the dropdown (where you defined input parameter in step 1) and you will see the parameter under Input tab
3. Now pass on the value or data item you want to call in object studio.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the data/collection in the output stage of the object.

To do this, you need to add it (still at object stage) to the 'End' Step. From there, name it, add a description, select a data type and show BP where to get the value from (your collection or data item).

Now, look in your Action properties of the Business Object at Process level. You will see under 'Outputs' the naming convention you gave to the data at Object level. You will now need to give the data somewhere to be stored in at process level (i usually give it the same name with _OO at the end (object output)).

In future, when passing data from Object to Process always remember to set your Object Outputs and Process Inputs at the same time to save an confusion when a process uses multiple data items.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set up outparameter in Output tab of "End" stage in the Action page which is called in Process. 
After the above step, Go to Process studio and refresh to see the outparameter in the business object.